# Read the data from CSV and put it into .rxt file

Tags: bash, sh

I am quite new to shell script and in the starting phase only I have a interested case. So the case is like I have a csv file that contains the data like:

```
ip_address,name,address,phone,email_id
192.168.1.1,ABC,Delhi,1234567,abc@gmail.com
192.168.1.2,MNO,Bangalore,1234567,mno@gmail.com
192.168.1.3,CDE,Pune,1234567,cde@gmail.com
192.168.1.4,PQR,Mumbai,1234567,pqr@gmail.com
192.168.1.5,XYZ,Noida,1234567,xyz@gmail.com
```

How can I write a shell script that will login to the server(192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2 and so on) and shell script should create .rxt file on that particular server inside /root directory and put the respective data to that rxt file like the below?

(i.e we can create directory like /root/data and inside this data we can put our rxt file as details.rxt)

```
ip_address=192.168.1.1
name=ABC
address=Delhi
phone=1234567
email_id=abc@gmail.com

ip_address=192.168.1.2
name=MNO
address=Bangalore
phone=1234567
email_id=mno@gmail.com
```

and so on.

---

**EDIT:**

I am trying to read the data from csv file like:

```
INPUT=serverdetails.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=“,”
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99}
while read ip_address name address phone email_id
do
  echo “IPAddress = $ip_address”
  echo “Name = $name”
  echo “Address = $address”
  echo "Telephone = $phone”
  echo “EmailID = $email_id”
done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Comment: start with researching `ssh` command, `scp` command, `rsync` command. Post achieving your goal using these commands into your question.

Comment: You could try `sed 's/$/\n/;s/,/\n/g' file` but this omits the column numbers.

Comment: If you are writing to `/root/data` you are running your script as `root`, that should be avoided for all but system admin tasks. Why not run the script as your normal user and find a new place to store the output file.

Comment: yes....here we go, we can create this file in another directory as well

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do the conversion part, ask a new question if you still need help with the ssh part:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="=" }
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        name[i] = $i
    }
    next
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        print name[i], $i
    }
    print ""
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
ip_address=192.168.1.1
name=ABC
address=Delhi
phone=1234567
email_id=abc@gmail.com

ip_address=192.168.1.2
name=MNO
address=Bangalore
phone=1234567
email_id=mno@gmail.com

ip_address=192.168.1.3
name=CDE
address=Pune
phone=1234567
email_id=cde@gmail.com

ip_address=192.168.1.4
name=PQR
address=Mumbai
phone=1234567
email_id=pqr@gmail.com

ip_address=192.168.1.5
name=XYZ
address=Noida
phone=1234567
email_id=xyz@gmail.com
```